# ORACLE_HOME environment variable causing confusion between Oracle Database and Oracle OC4J

Tags: database, oracle, oc4j, oracle-home

I'm having some Oracle trouble ...

I installed Oracle 11g Express Edition to here:

`C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server` .. so that there are folders such as:

`C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin`
`C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\config`
`C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\database`
`C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\lib`

and so on ... and the database is working fine ..

I now install OC4J to `C:\oc4j_extended_101350` .. so that there are folders such as:

`C:\oc4j_extended_101350\bin`

`C:\oc4j_extended_101350\j2ee`

`C:\oc4j_extended_101350\webservices`

and so on ..

Now OC4J requires me to define the environment variable `ORACLE_HOME`, which should be set to `C:\oc4j_extended_101350` in order for OC4J to work .. However, if I do this, the Oracle Database stops working ... and if I delete the `ORACLE_HOME` environment variable, or set it to where Oracle Database is installed, OC4J stops working ..

So is there any solution for this ? So that both OC4J and Oracle Database work ?

My system is Windows 7 64-bit, in case this matters ..

EDIT:

Also, I need BOTH to work together simultaneously with each other, so I'm not sure if a script solution will work or not ..

Answer (score 0):

Both installs require the ORACLE_HOME to be set, but to different values.  My expertise is UNIX, not Windows, and there the answer is to have the user or program set this variable correctly where it is needed.  It won't work with a single universal value, or with it unset.

Ex (pseudo syntax, not real commands):

```
ORACLE_HOME=DB_HOME
"start database"

ORACLE_HOME=OC4J HOME
"start OC4J"
```

In windows, maybe you can set this variable at the "service level", or perhaps you will need to go oldschool and do a batch file.  Like I said, I don't know Windows.

Don't worry, you can do it!!  It'll just take some trys.  Post your solution.